# Publish in debug mode but compiler removes code inside #if debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I'm only publishing in debug mode to test on my local machine and I was hoping the '#if debug' mode would work so that I could test features that I don't want in production yet.

When I publish in debug mode the web.config still has

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
</system.web>
```

but when I use reflector on the project's dll the code that was like this

```
#if debug
    PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
#endif
```

is non-existent. I figure the compiler has removed it.

NOTE: I'm NOT talking about a build, I'm talking about publishing. Doing a debug build works as I expect it to with the code above still present

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to get the compiler to include those bits of code when I'm publishing in debug mode? Am I going about this all wrong?

**Update:**
In response to @dash's comment my Package/Publish Web settings are:

[image: Package/Publish Web settings]

Comment: This works for me if I use `if #DEBUG`, not `if #debug` Also be sure to check the `Package/Publish Web` settings in the project properties to ensure `Debug` is the active build configuration when publishing.

Comment: What does your Build property page look like? Do you have `Define DEBUG constant` ticked? This works for me if I have Debug set in the Package/Publish Web page and that option ticked on the Build tab, and then doing a Publish - you can check using ILSpy (http://ilspy.net/) to make sure the code you are expecting has been included.

Comment: @dash yes Define DEBUG constant is ticked but it's not working for me. I've been using http://www.reflector.net/ to check the compiled code after a Publish but thanks for the tip about ILSpy, I haven't heard of that before. I'll give this another go with the settings you describe just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio:

```
1. Right click on your project choose properties.
2. Go to the "Build" tab
3. Select Release in the "Configuration" combobox.
4. Check the "Define DEBUG constant"-checkbox.
```

Make sure you don't forget to remove it before deploying to production.

Edit:
Since you are using lowercase debug you can instead of step 4 enter debug (lowercase) in "Conditional compilation symbols" in step 4:
[image: Conditional compilation symbols]

Comment: This looked promising but it's already ticked (and yes, I selected 'Release' for the configuration). I did notice when changing the configuration that the "Optimize code" checkbox is not ticked for debug but is ticked for release I'll give this a go

Comment: It is case sensitive so you should write #if DEBUG

Comment: Even though the web.config has lowercase debug? Are they not related?

Comment: I updated my post, you can enter debug (lowercase) in "Conditional compilation symbols" instead of checking "Define DEBUG constant"

Comment: Light bulb moment right there! Thanks @haiiaaa and everyone who contributed. Would you mind adding to your solution that "Define DEBUG constant" means it defines DEBUG in caps and it's case-sensitive and if you want to use lowercase debug you need to add it in "Conditional compilation symbols" as you've said. Also let the record show that the debug in web.config is unrelated to to the DEBUG constant

Answer (score 5):

C# preprocessor symbols are case-sensitive. Try:

```
#if DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks, I worked that out and mine is all lowercase debug. But this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You were right, my apologies and thanks! However, the key to my understanding what was happening here is that the debug defined in the web.config is unrelated to the DEBUG constant and that it can be changed in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is expected behavior.  The conditional compilation directives (e.g. `#if debug`) are considered at compile-time only.  The C# code is compiled when you build it.  What is the `compilation debug` option you pointed out then?  I'm not sure, but I think it changes how aspx pages are compiled or how the web site runs the built code, which happens just before the page is viewed instead of when the code is built.