# Debug mode on pre-compiled ASP.Net web sites

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've searched all over SO and Google but have not been able to clear my confusion about this. It seems like a very basic question but am just not clear about this.

It is advised everywhere that you should have `debug="false"` on your production websites because this can have a significant performance impact as debug symbols are loaded when the site is compiled. Agreed - and that is what I have on the production site.

Our website (not a web application) is a .Net 4.0 website that I pre-compile on VS 2012 (and previously on VS 2010) using the 'Publish Website' command. The site is pre-compiled to be "UI updateable".

My question is: If I pre-compile my site, then how does it matter what the production debug mode is set to? I assume debug symbols are not loaded and code optimization is already done in the pre-compiled DLLs. To test this, I've tried switching the debug mode before pre-compilation and it has **no effect whatsoever** on the size of the DLLs in the bin folder.

This post here: [Publish in debug mode but compiler removes code inside #if debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737047/publish-in-debug-mode-but-compiler-removes-code-inside-if-debug) seems to indicate the the debug mode has an effect on publishing the site as the author wants debug info in the DLLs.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Let me take a stab on your question, hoping i got you correctly.

Starting from Visual Studio 2010, a new concept called Config. Transforms. Those are files that help you customize the web.config files during deployment package generation which is triggered during 'Publish'

Those transforms are tied to the build configurations. So you will have one for debug called web.debug.config, and so on.
When you click publish or generate your package by any means, VS checks the current configuration, debug for example, to generate the right web.config.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not using this new feature. I have a single web.config file in the website on the development machine.